# How will I get a dynamic control in an aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-placeholder

I am working a project for my company. There I have encountered a problem. Therefore, I am showing an example of what I intended to do and what I am not being able to do.

In my aspx page I have button and placeholder. e.g.

```
 <asp:Button ID = "brnClickme" runat = "server" Text = "Click Me"onclick="brnClickme_Click" />
  <asp:PlaceHolder ID = "PH" runat = "server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

and in my aspc.cs file I have a dynamic control, say a Label that will changed its value after the Button is clicked

so I have written the code like this

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Text = "I am in the Place holder";
        PH.Controls.Add(label);
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


   protected void brnClickme_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label label = (Label)FindControl("label");
        label.Text = "After Click I am changed!";
    }
```

But in the Button click event, I am not finding the Label, so I am not being able to change the text of this dynamically created label with a click. I know I have made a mistake, so Please tell me what Mistake Have I made and What am I suppose to do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You tried add Label ID and after FindControl("ID")? label.ID = "identify"; FindControl("identify").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try finding the control in the placeholder

```
PH.FindControl("label");
```

You probably want to give the label an ID to make it easier to find when you create it.

```
label.ID = "findme";
```

then

```
PH.FindControl("findme");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not given your control an `ID` when creating it - this `ID` is what `FindContorl` uses in order to find that control.

You should also invoke `FindControl` on the container you added it to (`PH` in your case), as [podiluska](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1453411/podiluska) [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12246065/1583).

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.ID = "myLabel";
    label.Text = "I am in the Place holder";
    PH.Controls.Add(label);
}

protected void brnClickme_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = (Label)PH.FindControl("myLabel");
    label.Text = "After Click I am changed!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to recreate the Dynamic Controls in INIT as you have already done. and when you are searching for the LABEL in Button Click Try calling `templateFormPlaceholder.FindControl` instead.

Read this. It might help [Get text from dynamically created textbox in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992311/get-text-from-dynamically-created-textbox-in-asp-net)